# Receive written confirmation about non-breached data

Tags: gdpr, european-union, data-protection

**Context:**

- I am working for an institution which has recently suffered a data breach.
- There have also been articles in local press regarding the nature of the leaked data and claims about having access to extensive lists of breached data.
- On discussions with my institution's law department, I was (at last) informed about my leaked personal data at a descriptive level, however, the response seems incomplete compared to what I would expect that would have been leaked and what is also mentioned in the press.
- I am an EU resident working in an EU country, thus GDPR and any other relevant legislation apply here as well.

**Question:** Given the above, is it reasonable (and, furthermore, legally justified) to ask for a written confirmation of what personal data **have not been leaked?**

Comment: The problem is probably that you won't get a satisfying answer, as the company cannot know for certain.

Comment: @PMF Yes, this is something I am also considering - it seems indeed infeasible to have a concrete answer on that in most cases. However, I am also considering issuing a complaint to my DPA and I would like to know whether such a request is also legally justify - e.g., within the context of GDPR, as it is the case with the rights to access, deletion etc.

Comment: I would assume the company doesn't know what exactly was and wasn't leaked. Of course it would be a lot nicer of them to just tell you that instead of claiming you were not affected but what are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It is reasonable to ask but they may not know what information was leaked and not leaked. It might be beyond their knowledge and ability to know what did or did not leak.

Comment: @quarague Well, I am trying to figure out what is going on so as to decide whether to proceed to issue a complaint to my DPA. To that extent, I would like first to be sure that I have co-operated as much as possible with them (my institution). So, I would like to get a clear answer on what has been leaked - either in the form of copies of the leaked data or, if that is not possible, a clear statement of that, the very least, as you stated.

Comment: You can request all the data they hold, find out what has been leaked, and find the difference of the two? What kind of declaration are you wanting?

Comment: @StuartF Yes, it seems this is how I am going to proceed - I have already made a request for all of my personal data they are holding / processing. Well, I would like to figure out what has been leaked with as much certainty as possible, since I am working with them for several years, and there have been reports on press saying that payment information has been leaked, so this would result to (in)direct harm. To learn what has been leaked, though, I need their co-operation and some minimal formal guarantees (which, yet, I understand might be infeasible to get).